# Who is this person with a Ψ character and what is the CHAOS team?

Tags: discussion

Just like to drop a note on who I am and what my team does. I'm Seth, a member of the CHAOS (community development and evangelism) team at SE headquarters in New York. We're in the SE sites learning about how awesome the communities are. Much of our efforts are directed towards promoting the site and growing the community in a high quality and organic way. Personally, I have a background in psychology and am excited about tech startups, social psych and progress.

I will post in the meta with ideas we have for promoting Physics and engaging new users. Feel free to send me a note any time with ideas for community events, promotions, problems or lunch ideas. Also, I will pop in to chat regularly

Comment: Hi Seth! Good to have you around.